# How to merge two IQueryable lists

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I want to merge the records of two IQueryable lists in C#. I try

```
IQueryable<MediaType> list1 = values;
IQueryable<MediaType> list2 = values1;
obj.Concat(obj1);
```

and

```
IQueryable<MediaType> list1 = values;
IQueryable<MediaType> list2 = values1;
obj.Union(obj1);
```

but if `list1` is empty then the resultant list is also empty. In my case either `list1` can be empty but `list2` can have records. How should i merge them?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You're not using the return value - just like all other LINQ operators, the method doesn't change the *existing* sequence - it returns a *new* sequence. So try this:

```
var list3 = list1.Concat(list2);
```

or

```
var list4 = list1.Union(list2);
```

`Union` is a set operation - it returns distinct values.

`Concat` simply returns the items from the first sequence followed by the items from the second sequence; the resulting sequence can include duplicate items.

You can think of `Union` as `Concat` followed by `Distinct`.

Comment: Can the elements in an IQuerable be ordered? If so, do both of these statements preserve the order in the same way?

Comment: @CowboyBebop: They *can* be ordered - `IOrderedQueryable` extends `IQueryable`, for example. In LINQ to Objects, the order is preserved with these operations - but I doubt that it's guaranteed for out-of-process query providers.

Comment: Interesting part is you can still chain the query using Union, so it wont be executed and the result would still be an `IQueryable<T>` which helped me alot in my case.

Comment: Hello, when I use this codes for IQueryable methods it shows error that result is wrong. iq1 = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.CategoryId == 1); and iq2 = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.CategoryId==2); then iqResult = iq1.Concat(iq2); when I debug in this line I get error.

Comment: @AProgrammer: I suggest you ask a new question with much more detail than "I get error".

Answer (score 6):

Even

```
var result = Enumerable.Concat(list1, list2);
```

doesn't work?

And be sure that lists are empty, not null:

```
var result = Enumerable.Concat(
    list1 ?? Enumerable.Empty<MediaType>()
    list2 ?? Enumerable.Empty<MediaType>());
```

Also try:

```
var result = Enumerable.Concat(
    list1.AsEnumerable(),
    list2.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: @Fraz: Please try each of my variant and report the results

Answer (score -2):

Another option I found:
Declare:
    `IEnumerable<int> usersIds = new int[0];`
For example inside a loop:

```
foreach (var id in Ids) {
            IQueryable<int> _usersIds = bl.GetUsers(id).Select(x => x.UserID);
            usersIds = usersIds.Concat(_usersIds);
        }  
var ids = usersIds.Distinct();
```

Now usersIds and ids(as distinct) contains the id of all users as IEnumerable -int-