# How to concat multiple selects with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have main select which looks like this:

```
protected IQueryable<Answers> GetActualAnswers<TAns>(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, long? statusId) where TAns: AnswersBase
{
_contex.Set<TAns>.Where(x => x.Type == VoteType.Good)
.Select(vv => new Answers
        {
             CreatedAt = vv.CreatedAt,
             StatusId = vv.StatusId,
             Type = vv.Type ,
             AnswerInGuideStatusId = vv.AnswerInGuideStatusId
        }
}
```

I'm using this method in two simple queries:

```
 var result1 = GetActualAnswers<JournalAnswers>(start, end, statusId)
    .Select(j => new UnitedAnswers
    {
         Question = j.Question,
    }

    var result2 = GetActualAnswers<BoAnswers>(start, end, statusId)
    .Select(b => new UnitedAnswers
    {
         Prospects = b.Prospects ,
    }

var mainResult = result1.Concat(result2);
```

I get errors:

```
Sql = Sql = '((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<UnitedAnswers>)result1).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
Sql = Sql = '((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<UnitedAnswers>)result2).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
Sql = Sql = '((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<UnitedAnswers>)mainResult).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Is it possible to use several Selects? May be someone can give advice with this query?

Comment: Do the two queries result1 and result2 work, when executed separatly ? "Not supported might be something in the 4! classes in your queries you are using. Especially the Answers class does not have a Question or Prospects properties set, how can you copy them ? And why you first copy to Answers, than to UnitedAnswers ? Why not to UnitedAnswers right away, would cause less complication.

Comment: Where do you think `j.Question` and `b.Prospects` will come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, I was wondering where the property `j.Question` and `b.Prospects` you get, While in the method `GetActualAnswers` you did not get the value of 2 properties above.

**Secondly**, At the method `GetActualAnswers` you were returning `IQueryable`, so you should check `empty` instead of `null` value

Then your case might look like this

```
var mainResult = Enumerable.Concat(
resut1 ?? Enumerable.Empty<UnitedAnswers>(),
resut2 ?? Enumerable.Empty<UnitedAnswers>()
```

**or**

```
  var mainResult = Enumerable.Concat(
    result1.AsEnumerable(),
    result2.AsEnumerable());
```

The following links are useful for you.

1. [How to merge two IQueryable lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003813/how-to-merge-two-iqueryable-lists)
2. [Enumerable.AsEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Please let me know if you need any help. @TAD

Comment: Unfortunately this answer didn't help me. I had changed conception to bypass this problem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: `I had changed conception to bypass this problem`, You mean my code worked but you changed your solution instead of `concat multiple selects`?

Comment: Your code doesn't help. There is problem with field. It should be simple dto object. So I use Automapper to generate ef query before execute them.